# redis consuming huge amount of memory

Tags: database, magento, caching, redis

we have recently installed Redis Cache for our magento based sites.

we 2 websites on our server both using same redis server, our server is based on linux with centos.

the issue we are facing is that redis is consuming quite a lot of RAM, and it is growing by every day.

we have set some values on our magento local.xml file for redis

```
        <redis_session>    
        <host>xxxxxxx</host>                          
        <port>xxxx</port>
        <password></password>                            
        <timeout>2.5</timeout>                             
        <persistent></persistent>                            
        <db>1</db>                                          
        <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold>  
        <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>            
        <log_level>1</log_level>                           
        <max_concurrency>6</max_concurrency>               
        <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>     
        <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>
        <first_lifetime>86400</first_lifetime>               
        <bot_first_lifetime>60</bot_first_lifetime>
        <bot_lifetime>7200</bot_lifetime>           
        <disable_locking>0</disable_locking>        
        <min_lifetime>60</min_lifetime>             
        <max_lifetime>2592000</max_lifetime>
       <automatic_cleaning_factor>1</automatic_cleaning_factor>        
    </redis_session>
```

it seems like we do not have an expire set to it, plus there is no memory usage limit either.

i know there are few instruction on internet for setting expire but there is nothing for use with magento in easy way.

all help is apreciated.

Comment: Isn't max_lifetime the expiry? Have you tried setting it to something lower?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity what do you think this question is about? i am asking a program or software which isnt working as it should be, there are hundreds of questions about redis on stackoverflow.com do your research mate.

Comment: @ChrisTanner yes i did try to lover this, currently it is on 14 days, before it was on 30 days. the RAM usage is increasing by every day

Comment: @shafiq - It's not about programming. Simple as that. If one person (or hundreds) got away with murder it doesn't make murder legal. This is a programming site and this question is not about programming. Have a read of what's [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. It's quite clear. You should do the research.